# MapKit auto-zooming back to current location every time I scroll away from current location

Tags: swift, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer

I've built a basic app in X-code which shows the user's location and also zooms in automatically to the user's location. I'd like to be able to move around the map since I will have important annotations set up around the user's location, but every time I navigate to a different part of the map I am dragged back to my zoomed-in location. I was advised to "*handle the pan gesture on the map and when the map is in pan state then don't zoom. You can control this with a simple bool flag to zoom or not.*" Please advise on how to fix this issue.

```
import UIKit
```

import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //delegates
    locationManager.delegate = self
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    
    
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
}


//zoom
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapView.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you set `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` the device's location hardware (GPS/radio receiver, etc) begins the job of actually trying to determine the location. But, it will continue to do that until you tell it to `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` So your app will receive an ongoing stream of location updates that are all dealt with by your mapView delegate function `mapView didUpdate userLocation` Each time that method is called you are instructing the mapView to zoom to your user's location and so it is fighting and over-riding any other action the user is trying to perform at the same time, like scrolling, zooming, etc.

The stream of location updates will each have a figure for the uncertainty (`.horizontalAccuracy`) in the location measurement (+/- 60m or whatever) and each successive update will hopefully have a smaller uncertainty than the previous one but that isn't guaranteed depending on the local physical environment.

A common approach is, within `mapView didUpdate userLocation`, to keep a copy of the last update and compare it with each successive update and if the new one is more accurate than the previous one, save the new, else discard. Calculate the distance between new and old and when that distance is less than your previously decided minimum (`kCLLocationAccuracyBest` or 500m, 50m, 10m, whatever) then `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`

Until you make the decision to stop updating locations, then you should avoid any kind of auto-zooming as the behaviour will frustrate your user.

This is a typical method, but would need modifying for your particular use:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let newLocation = locations.last!
    // We've been passed a cached result so ignore and continue.
    if newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow < -5 {
        return
    }
    // horizontalAccuracy < 0 indicates invalid result so ignore and continue.
    if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
        return
    }
    // Calculate the distance between the new and previous locations.
    var distance = CLLocationDistance(Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    if let location = location { // location is my previously stored value.
        distance = newLocation.distance(from: location)
    }
    // If newLocation is more accurate than the previous (if previous exists) then use it.
    if location == nil || location!.horizontalAccuracy > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy {
        lastLocationError = nil
        location = newLocation

        // When newLocation's accuracy is better than our desired accuracy then stop.
        if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= locationManager.desiredAccuracy {
            stopLocationManager()
        }
    } else if distance < 5 {
        let timeInterval = newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSince(location!.timestamp)
        if timeInterval > 10 {
            stopLocationManager()
        }
    }

    print(newLocation)
}
```

Sometimes the updates simply never result in an accuracy that satisfies our requirements so there is a timer in there to kill the location hunt after 10 seconds.

I would suggest, that rather than using an automatic zoom to the user's location, that you introduce a button that does the same thing. That way the user knows exactly when and why the behaviour occurs and if they're choosing to zoom to their location they won't be scrolling at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got your answer yet but here is how I took care of it.

I simply added a var called tracking which is set to true at start.
I called the locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() inside my viewDidLoad, then set the tracking variable to false.

```
super.viewDidLoad()
checkLocationServices()
    
customers = ReadTextFile()
for customer in customers {
    addCustomPin(customer:customer)
}
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
tracking = false
```

Inside my checkLocationServices(), which calls checkLocationAuthorization()
I added

```
if tracking {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

This way, the first time the app calls the checkLocationServices, my tracking var is true, so it checks for the location.

If I wanted to turn the setting back ON, I just need to turn the variable back to true.